# can't fetch image from api in nextjs - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') NEXTJS

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, nextjs-image

I can't seem to fetch an image from the api, not sure what's going on. What am I missing here?

I also keep getting this error in the browser.

Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {}
null

images in `console.log` produces undefined.

```
function Images({images}) {
 
    
    return (
        <div>
    {images?.map((image)=> (
        <Image src={image.url}/>
    ))}    
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res= await fetch ('https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/hotels?collection-id=OBMNG')
    const images = await res.json()

return {
    props: {
        images,
    },
}

}

export default Images
```

Comment: so an image is loaded on your side? just this 
just standard webpack errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested structure and you should do like this. (nested maps)

```
function Images({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data?.length &&
        data.map((item) => item.images.map((image) => <img src={image?.url || ''} height={100} width={100} />))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/hotels?collection-id=OBMNG');
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

export default Images;
```

**Update:**

If you have a problem with next/image you should add the configuration in the **next.config.js** file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...otherConfigs,
  images: {
    domains: ['www.HOSTNAME.com'], // hostname of the img url
  },
};
```

Here are the images:
[image]

Comment: throws this erro - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Answer (score 0):

Check `images` is array.

And assign a default value.

```
// getStaticProps
return {
    props: {
        images : images ?? [],
    },
}
```

or

```
function Images({ images = [] }) {...}
```

Comment: the array is empty

Comment: this throws erros  // getStaticProps
return {
    props: {
        images ?? [],
    },
}

Answer (score 0):

```
{data?.image_url?.length &&
   data?.image_url?.map((item: any) => (
     <img src={item.url || 'image'} height={300} width={400} />
))}
```